# How to stream via VLC with RTSP

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a problem streaming video using VLC. I want to use RTSP protocol. I have set the streaming as follows:

- Open VLC;
- Press CTRL+S in order to open streaming options;
- Add the video file;
- Add destination setup as RTSP, port 8554 and path "/";
- Activated transcoding;
- Press "Stream";

Using the same pc, I went on "localhost:8554", but the browser shows me a "404 Client error (/)" page with a link to VideoLAN (which is the company that have produced VLC).

How can I watch my video streaming, and how can I access to it from another PC?

Comment: I would assume VLC only provides the RTSP service but you are expecting that it also provides a web based player (which is isn't the case). So the answer is: "use an RTSP video player software" or a different RTSP server that also provides a web based player.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm trying to use a second instance of VLC to read the stream.   I'm getting "cannot open stream" errors.

Answer (score -2):

It may be a firewall issue. Firewall may block incoming connections on port 8554.

I am not sure how make available connectivity on Windows, but you can run this command in Linux:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8554 -j ACCEPT
```

It will allow incoming traffic on 8554 port

Comment: he opened it on the same PC....